# sudo still ask for password when NOPASSWD is used

Tags: sudo

I want to run this script (it is post-receive hook of git repository):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Executing post-receive hook as user `id` using `which sudo`"
sudo -l
sudo -n bash /var/project/autotest/autotest.sh
```

It should run without asking for password, but I got following output:

```
Executing post-receive hook as user uid=1005(martinjonas) gid=1001(martinjonas)
groups=1001(martinjonas),1009(lifeweb),1017(project) using /usr/bin/sudo
Matching Defaults entries for martinjonas on this host:
    env_reset

User martinjonas may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /var/project/autotest/autotest.sh
sudo: sorry, a password is required to run sudo
```

As you can see acording to outputo of sudo -l I am supposed to be able run /var/project/autotest/autotest.sh without password, but sudo still asks for password.

This is my sudoers file (it is whole file no additional entries there):

```
# /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.

Defaults        env_reset

# Host alias specification
# User alias specification
# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
# (Note that later entries override this, so you might need to move
# it further down)
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
#
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

www-data        ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/svn up
%project       ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /var/project/autotest/autotest.sh
```

I try to search for answer but only possible problems I found are wrong sudo used or wrong order of entires in sudoers, which I both disproved.

We use Debian 6.0 2. on this server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have `NOPASSWD` entry for `/var/project/autotest/autotest.sh`, but your command running `bash /var/project/autotest/autotest.sh` - it's different command and that's why it forbidden

remove `bash` and all should work fine.